# Localhost redirects to https but Chromium does not

Tags: 18.04, firefox, security, connection, https

I'm facing a problem while developing some sites.  Firefox redirects to `https` and gives an error due to a connection security failure, but it works great with Chromium (doesn't redirect).

I've been Googling and trying a few things, but I can't solve this.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.1 64-bit with the latest updates.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that at least one of the sites you developed and connected to on `localhost` had the [HSTS header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security) header set. The result of Firefox reading that header would be

> The HTTP Strict Transport Security header informs the browser that it
>   should never load a site using HTTP and should automatically convert
>   all attempts to access the site using HTTP to HTTPS requests instead.

To fix this on Firefox, open the `browser history` by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>. Next, locate any `localhost` site you've visited and right-click on that site. Lastly, click on `Forget About This Site`

To fix this on Chrome, go to the `location bar` (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>) and type [chrome://net-internals/#hsts](http://chrome://net-internals/#hsts). Next, go to the `Delete domain security policies`-header and type `localhost` and click `delete`. If you want to see what headers are set for `localhost` first before you remove them, use the `query`-functionality under the `Query HSTS/PKP domain`-header.

The last thing you should do is figure out which of your sites sent/are sending the HSTS header in the first place. I don't know what language your backend is running, but something like Spring Security will [add the HSTS header by default](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/headers.html#headers-hsts) when enabling web security, for instance using the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation.

Comment: This didnt work in Firefox, the thing as said before is that in chromium it works perfect. Im trying to use lastfm api in a project, and dont know why, firefox redirects to https and then i cant acces the page as connection security failureChromium works great without this redirection. Im using javascript and ajax...thanks

Comment: worked for me..